# Pythonのコードで定義したつもりが、not definedと表示される

Tags: python, edinet

初心者ですが、企業の財務諸表分析のためにPythonコードを勉強しております。

[pythonで財務分析:EDINETから四半期ごとの情報を取得する](https://kiseno-log.com/2020/08/23/python%E3%81%A7%E8%B2%A1%E5%8B%99%E5%88%86%E6%9E%90edinet%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E5%9B%9B%E5%8D%8A%E6%9C%9F%E6%B1%BA%E7%AE%97%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)

上記のwebサイトを参考に、まずサンプル（企業名などもサンプルと同じままにしています）と同じように自分のPCでデータが得られるか検証しているのですが、下記のエラーが出てしまいます。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a5273144dfbe> in <module>
    142 
    143 # XBRLからデータ形式を変換
--> 144 df_dic = zip_to_df(file_path_list)
    145 
    146 # 営業利益部分抽出

NameError: name 'file_path_list' is not defined
```

コードを一つずつ確認すると、
#zipファイルパスのリストの作成
の部分でfile_path_listは作成しているつもりなのですが、なぜnot definedと出てしまうか分からず苦戦しております。
分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけますでしょうか（初心者でも分かるようにしてくれると嬉しいです）。
宜しくお願い致します。

**ソースコード:**

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
import requests
import json
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import glob
#XBRLをpython形式に変換するライブラリのフォルダパス
sys.path.append(r'C://Users//junji//AppData//Roaming//Microsoft//Windows//Start Menu//Programs//Python 3.9')
from xbrl_proc import read_xbrl_from_zip
import urllib3
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def get_list(start,end,company_list):
    '''指定した期間、報告書種類、会社で報告書を取得し、取得したファイルのパスの辞書を返す'''
    #取得期間の日付リストを作成
    day_term = [start + timedelta(days=i) for i in range((end - start).days)]
    
    #データ抜出時に使用する、有価証券報告書および四半期報告書のコードの設定
    ordinance_code = "010"
    form_code_quart ="043000" # 四半期報告書
    form_code_securities ="030000" #有価証券報告書
    
    #EDINETのAPIで、書類一覧を取得し、各日ごとに必要な書類の項目を抜き出し
    quart_list =[] # 四半期報告書のリスト
    securities_list =[] # 四半期報告書のリスト

    print('EDINETへのアクセスを開始')
    for i,day in enumerate(day_term):
        url = "https://disclosure.edinet-fsa.go.jp/api/v1/documents.json"
        params = {"date": day, "type": 2}
        
        #進捗表示
        if i % 50 == 0:
            print(f'{i}日目：{day}を開始')
        
        #EDINETから1日の書類一覧を取得
        res = requests.get(url, params=params, verify=False)
        
        #必要な書類の項目を抜き出し
        if res.ok:
            json_data = res.json()
            
            for data in json_data['results']:
                #指定した会社の指定した書類を抜き出し
                if data['ordinanceCode'] == ordinance_code and data['formCode'] == form_code_quart and data['filerName'].replace('株式会社', '') in company_list:
                    quart_list.append(data)
                elif data['ordinanceCode'] == ordinance_code and data['formCode'] == form_code_securities and data['filerName'].replace('株式会社', '') in company_list:
                    securities_list.append(data)
                    
        else:
            print(f'アクセス失敗かも{day}')
    
    list_dic = {'四半期報告書':quart_list,'有価証券報告書':securities_list} 
    
    return list_dic

def get_zip(list_dic,quart_dir_path,securities_dir_path):
    '''取得したいデータをzipファイルで取得してファイルパスのリストを返す'''
    
    dir_path_dic = {'四半期報告書':quart_dir_path,'有価証券報告書':securities_dir_path}
    file_path_dic = {'四半期報告書':[],'有価証券報告書':[]} # ダウンロードした有価証券報告書のパスを格納する辞書   

    for key in list_dic.keys():
        
        #すでにzipをDLしている場合のため、既存のdocIDリストを取得
        files = os.listdir(dir_path_dic[key])
        existing_docID_list = [file.split('.')[0].split('_')[1] for file in files if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path_dic[key], file))]
        
        print(f'{key}ファイルのDLを開始')
        for i, doc in enumerate(list_dic[key]):
            #zipファイルパスのリストの作成
            file_name = doc['filerName'].replace('株式会社', '') + '_' + doc['docID']
            file_path =  os.path.join(dir_path_dic[key], file_name + ".zip")
            file_path_dic[key].append(file_path)
            
            #所有していないファイルの場合はDLを行う
            if doc['docID'] not in existing_docID_list:
                #ファイルを取得
                url_zip = "https://disclosure.edinet-fsa.go.jp/api/v1/documents/" + doc['docID']
                params_zip = {"type": 1}

                #進捗表示
                if i % 100 == 0:
                    print(f'{i}ファイル目を開始')

                #データのDL
                res_zip = requests.get(url_zip, params=params_zip, verify=False, stream=True)

                #zipとして保存
                if res_zip.status_code == 200:
                    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                        for chunk in res_zip.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                            if chunk:
                                f.write(chunk)
                                f.flush()

    return file_path_dic

def zip_to_df(file_path_dic):
    '''ダウンロードしたzipをdfに変換して各会社のdicにして返す'''
    
    all_df_dic = {}
    for key in file_path_dic.keys():
        print(f'{key}データの変換を開始')        
        df_dic = {}
        for i,company_zip in enumerate(file_path_dic[key]):
            # 進捗表示
            if i % 100 == 0:
                print(f'{i}ファイル目を開始')
            company_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(company_zip))[0].split('_')[0]
            doc_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(company_zip))[0].split('_')[1]

            if company_name not in df_dic:# 会社が辞書中に存在しない場合
                df_dic[company_name] = {}
                df_dic[company_name] = read_xbrl_from_zip(company_zip)[0]
            elif company_name in df_dic:# 会社が辞書中に存在する場合
                df_dic[company_name] = pd.concat( [df_dic[company_name],read_xbrl_from_zip(company_zip)[0]])
        
        all_df_dic[key] = df_dic

    return all_df_dic

#会社のリストを読み込み
company_list = ['ホウスイ','カネコ種苗']

#取得期間の設定：直近n日分
delta_day = 100
end = date.today()
start = date.today() - timedelta(days=delta_day)

#ダウンロードしたデータのフォルダパス
quart_dir_path = r'C://Users//junji//Desktop//Kabu//CompanyXBRL2//'
securities_dir_path = r'C://Users//junji//Desktop//Kabu//CompanyXBRL2//'


#XBRLデータの取得 
list_dic = get_list(start,end,company_list)
file_path_dic = get_zip(list_dic,quart_dir_path,securities_dir_path)

#XBRLからデータ形式を変換
df_dic = zip_to_df(file_path_list)

#営業利益部分抽出
quart = all_df_dic['四半期報告書']['カネコ種苗']
quart_oi = quart[(quart['tag'] == 'OperatingIncome') & (quart['context'] == 'CurrentYTDDuration')]
quart_oi = quart_oi[['第N期','終了日','値']].sort_values('終了日')
quart_oi = quart_oi.rename({'終了日':'Date','値':'OperatingIncome'},axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
quart_oi['type'] = '四半期報告書'

securities = all_df_dic['有価証券報告書']['カネコ種苗']
securities_oi = securities[(securities['tag'] == 'OperatingIncome') & (securities['context'] == 'CurrentYearDuration')]
securities_oi = securities_oi[['第N期','終了日','値']].sort_values('終了日')
securities_oi = securities_oi.rename({'終了日':'Date','値':'OperatingIncome'},axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
securities_oi['type'] = '有価証券報告書'

oi_df = pd.concat([quart_oi,securities_oi]).sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)

#各四半期ごとの営業利益や、前年同期比の売上高営業利益率の変化を計算
oi_df['tempOperatingIncome'] =  oi_df['OperatingIncome'] - oi_df['OperatingIncome'].shift(1)
oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'] = oi_df['OperatingIncome'].mask(oi_df['第N期'] == 0, oi_df['tempOperatingIncome'])
oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'] = oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'].mask(oi_df['第N期'] == 3, oi_df['tempOperatingIncome'])
oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'] = oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'].mask(oi_df['第N期'] == 2, oi_df['tempOperatingIncome'])
oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome_YoYchangerate'] = oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'] / oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'].shift(4)

#棒グラフで可視化
oi_df.plot.bar(x='Date', y='CalcOperatingIncome', rot=45)

oi_df.plot.bar(x='Date', y='CalcOperatingIncome_YoYchangerate', rot=45)
```

Comment: `df_dic = zip_to_df(file_path_list)` を `all_df_dic = zip_to_df(file_path_dic)` に変更するとよろしいかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！勉強になりました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"zipファイルパスのリストの作成" が含まれているのは `get_zip` の中であり、これを呼び出した結果は以下の `file_path_dic` で通り受け取っているように見えます。

```
file_path_dic = get_zip(list_dic,quart_dir_path,securities_dir_path)
```

`zip_to_df` の引数に適切な引数を設定すればよさそうです。

```
df_dic = zip_to_df(file_path_dic)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！おっしゃる通り、file_path_dicで受け取っていましたので、引数の修正で次のステップまで進むことができました。