# "BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" エラーが解消できない

Tags: python, edinet

過去にも類似の投稿があり、同じところでエラーが出ていたので、回答を参考にして "file_path_dic" に変更したところ、そこは通過しましたがすぐ下で下記のような別なエラーが出てしまいました。

このエラーに対処出来ずに困ってます。ご教授いただければ幸いです。

[Pythonのコードで定義したつもりが、not definedと表示される](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/77901)

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
EDINETへのアクセスを開始
0日目：2021-02-22を開始
50日目：2021-04-13を開始
100日目：2021-06-02を開始
150日目：2021-07-22を開始
200日目：2021-09-10を開始
250日目：2021-10-30を開始
300日目：2021-12-19を開始
350日目：2022-02-07を開始
四半期報告書ファイルのDLを開始
0ファイル目を開始
有価証券報告書ファイルのDLを開始
0ファイル目を開始
四半期報告書データの変換を開始
0ファイル目を開始
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7852/759562761.py in <module>
    142 
    143 #XBRLからデータ形式を変換
--> 144 all_df_dic = zip_to_df(file_path_dic)
    145 
    146 #営業利益部分抽出

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7852/759562761.py in zip_to_df(file_path_dic)
    116             if company_name not in df_dic:# 会社が辞書中に存在しない場合
    117                 df_dic[company_name] = {}
--> 118                 df_dic[company_name] = read_xbrl_from_zip(company_zip)[0]
    119             elif company_name in df_dic:# 会社が辞書中に存在する場合
    120                 df_dic[company_name] = pd.concat( [df_dic[company_name],read_xbrl_from_zip(company_zip)[0]])

~\OneDrive\デスクトップ\EDINET\Zip\Kiseno\xbrl_reader_for_edinet_20180702-00\xbrl_proc.py in read_xbrl_from_zip(xbrl)
     25 戻り値 pandas.DataFrame のリスト"""
     26     # zipからファイルデータ取得
---> 27     file_datas = xbrl_zip_get_xbrl_files(
     28         xbrl,
     29         RE_XBRL_FILE_MATCH,

~\OneDrive\デスクトップ\EDINET\Zip\Kiseno\xbrl_reader_for_edinet_20180702-00\xbrl_zip.py in get_xbrl_files(file, re_xbrl_file_match)
     15 
     16     # zipオブジェクト作成
---> 17     with ZipFile(file, 'r') as zip_obj:
     18         # ファイルリスト取得
     19         infos = zip_obj.infolist()

~\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel, strict_timestamps)
   1255         try:
   1256             if mode == 'r':
-> 1257                 self._RealGetContents()
   1258             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1259                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

~\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1322             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1323         if not endrec:
-> 1324             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1325         if self.debug > 1:
   1326             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
---------------------------------------------------------
```

ソースコードを改めて記載します。下記ソースコードにはページの作者による自作のPython ライブラリをダウンロードして使うことになっています。

- [EDINET XBRLを読み込むPythonライブラリ](https://srbrnote.work/archives/1430)
- [xbrl_reader_for_edinet_20180702-00.zip](https://srbrnote.work/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/xbrl_reader_for_edinet_20180702-00.zip)

**実行環境:**

Windows 11
Pyhton 3.9.7
Jupyter Notebook

---

**ソースコード:**

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
import requests
import json
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import glob
#XBRLをpython形式に変換するライブラリのフォルダパス
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\Osamu\OneDrive\デスクトップ\EDINET\Zip\Kiseno\xbrl_reader_for_edinet_20180702-00")
from xbrl_proc import read_xbrl_from_zip
import urllib3
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def get_list(start,end,company_list):
    '''指定した期間、報告書種類、会社で報告書を取得し、取得したファイルのパスの辞書を返す'''
    #取得期間の日付リストを作成
    day_term = [start + timedelta(days=i) for i in range((end - start).days)]
    
    #データ抜出時に使用する、有価証券報告書および四半期報告書のコードの設定
    ordinance_code = "010"
    form_code_quart ="043000" # 四半期報告書
    form_code_securities ="030000" #有価証券報告書
    
    #EDINETのAPIで、書類一覧を取得し、各日ごとに必要な書類の項目を抜き出し
    quart_list =[] # 四半期報告書のリスト
    securities_list =[] # 四半期報告書のリスト

    print('EDINETへのアクセスを開始')
    for i,day in enumerate(day_term):
        url = "https://disclosure.edinet-fsa.go.jp/api/v1/documents.json"
        params = {"date": day, "type": 2}
        
        #進捗表示
        if i % 50 == 0:
            print(f'{i}日目：{day}を開始')
        
        #EDINETから1日の書類一覧を取得
        res = requests.get(url, params=params, verify=False)
        
        #必要な書類の項目を抜き出し
        if res.ok:
            json_data = res.json()
            
            for data in json_data['results']:
                #指定した会社の指定した書類を抜き出し
                if data['ordinanceCode'] == ordinance_code and data['formCode'] == form_code_quart and data['filerName'].replace('株式会社', '') in company_list:
                    quart_list.append(data)
                elif data['ordinanceCode'] == ordinance_code and data['formCode'] == form_code_securities and data['filerName'].replace('株式会社', '') in company_list:
                    securities_list.append(data)
                    
        else:
            print(f'アクセス失敗かも{day}')
    
    list_dic = {'四半期報告書':quart_list,'有価証券報告書':securities_list} 
    
    return list_dic

def get_zip(list_dic,quart_dir_path,securities_dir_path):
    '''取得したいデータをzipファイルで取得してファイルパスのリストを返す'''
    
    dir_path_dic = {'四半期報告書':quart_dir_path,'有価証券報告書':securities_dir_path}
    file_path_dic = {'四半期報告書':[],'有価証券報告書':[]} # ダウンロードした有価証券報告書のパスを格納する辞書   

    for key in list_dic.keys():
        
        #すでにzipをDLしている場合のため、既存のdocIDリストを取得
        files = os.listdir(dir_path_dic[key])
        existing_docID_list = [file.split('.')[0].split('_')[1] for file in files if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path_dic[key], file))]
        
        print(f'{key}ファイルのDLを開始')
        for i, doc in enumerate(list_dic[key]):
            #zipファイルパスのリストの作成
            file_name = doc['filerName'].replace('株式会社', '') + '_' + doc['docID']
            file_path =  os.path.join(dir_path_dic[key], file_name + ".zip")
            file_path_dic[key].append(file_path)
            
            #所有していないファイルの場合はDLを行う
            if doc['docID'] not in existing_docID_list:
                #ファイルを取得
                url_zip = "https://disclosure.edinet-fsa.go.jp/api/v1/documents/" + doc['docID']
                params_zip = {"type": 1}

                #進捗表示
                if i % 100 == 0:
                    print(f'{i}ファイル目を開始')

                #データのDL
                res_zip = requests.get(url_zip, params=params_zip, verify=False, stream=True)

                #zipとして保存
                if res_zip.status_code == 200:
                    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                        for chunk in res_zip.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                            if chunk:
                                f.write(chunk)
                                f.flush()

    return file_path_dic

def zip_to_df(file_path_dic):
    '''ダウンロードしたzipをdfに変換して各会社のdicにして返す'''
    
    all_df_dic = {}
    for key in file_path_dic.keys():
        print(f'{key}データの変換を開始')        
        df_dic = {}
        for i,company_zip in enumerate(file_path_dic[key]):
            # 進捗表示
            if i % 100 == 0:
                print(f'{i}ファイル目を開始')
            company_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(company_zip))[0].split('_')[0]
            doc_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(company_zip))[0].split('_')[1]

            if company_name not in df_dic:# 会社が辞書中に存在しない場合
                df_dic[company_name] = {}
                df_dic[company_name] = read_xbrl_from_zip(company_zip)[0]
            elif company_name in df_dic:# 会社が辞書中に存在する場合
                df_dic[company_name] = pd.concat( [df_dic[company_name],read_xbrl_from_zip(company_zip)[0]])
        
        all_df_dic[key] = df_dic

    return all_df_dic

#会社のリストを読み込み
company_list = ['ホウスイ','カネコ種苗']

#取得期間の設定：直近n日分
delta_day = 400
end = date.today()
start = date.today() - timedelta(days=delta_day)

#ダウンロードしたデータのフォルダパス
quart_dir_path = r"C:\Users\Osamu\OneDrive\デスクトップ\EDINET\Zip\Kiseno\quart"
securities_dir_path = r"C:\Users\Osamu\OneDrive\デスクトップ\EDINET\Zip\Kiseno\securities"


#XBRLデータの取得 
list_dic = get_list(start,end,company_list)
file_path_dic = get_zip(list_dic,quart_dir_path,securities_dir_path)

#XBRLからデータ形式を変換
all_df_dic = zip_to_df(file_path_dic)

#営業利益部分抽出
quart = all_df_dic['四半期報告書']['カネコ種苗']
quart_oi = quart[(quart['tag'] == 'OperatingIncome') & (quart['context'] == 'CurrentYTDDuration')]
quart_oi = quart_oi[['第N期','終了日','値']].sort_values('終了日')
quart_oi = quart_oi.rename({'終了日':'Date','値':'OperatingIncome'},axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
quart_oi['type'] = '四半期報告書'

securities = all_df_dic['有価証券報告書']['カネコ種苗']
securities_oi = securities[(securities['tag'] == 'OperatingIncome') & (securities['context'] == 'CurrentYearDuration')]
securities_oi = securities_oi[['第N期','終了日','値']].sort_values('終了日')
securities_oi = securities_oi.rename({'終了日':'Date','値':'OperatingIncome'},axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
securities_oi['type'] = '有価証券報告書'

oi_df = pd.concat([quart_oi,securities_oi]).sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)

#各四半期ごとの営業利益や、前年同期比の売上高営業利益率の変化を計算
oi_df['tempOperatingIncome'] =  oi_df['OperatingIncome'] - oi_df['OperatingIncome'].shift(1)
oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'] = oi_df['OperatingIncome'].mask(oi_df['第N期'] == 0, oi_df['tempOperatingIncome'])
oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'] = oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'].mask(oi_df['第N期'] == 3, oi_df['tempOperatingIncome'])
oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'] = oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'].mask(oi_df['第N期'] == 2, oi_df['tempOperatingIncome'])
oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome_YoYchangerate'] = oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'] / oi_df['CalcOperatingIncome'].shift(4)

#棒グラフで可視化
oi_df.plot.bar(x='Date', y='CalcOperatingIncome', rot=45)

oi_df.plot.bar(x='Date', y='CalcOperatingIncome_YoYchangerate', rot=45)
```

Comment: 問題の再現・調査のためにはどなたかが作成されているらしいライブラリが必要ですが、こちらの記事でよろしいでしょうか？ [EDINET XBRLを読み込むPythonライブラリ](https://srbrnote.work/archives/1430) 正確なところを記事に追加しておいてください。

Comment: Windows10, Python 3.10.3の環境でJupyter Notebookを使わないPythonインタプリタ単体で、quart,securities,xbrl_reader_for_edinet_20180702-00の各サブディレクトリをカレントディレクトリの直下に作成・指定して動作させてみると問題無く終了しました。Jupyter Notebookでは無いので表示はされませんが、処理結果のオブジェクトは出来ています。何かJupyter Notebookか、Python版数か、その他何かの環境問題かもしれませんね。

Comment: エラーが "File is not a zip file (ファイルが ZIP ファイルではない)" なので、まずは ZIP ファイルのダウンロードが正しく行えているのか辺りから確認してみてください。 / 保存先が OneDrive になっているのも個人的には気になるところです。

Comment: @kunif ライブラリの情報を追加しました。

Comment: @cubick 保存先のフォルダーをOneDriveから外して実行してみましたが結果は同じでした。一方でいろんな会社を試したところすべてのZipファイルを正常に取得できた場合にはエラーとならずに実行完了できました。どうすればすべてのZipファイルを正常に取得できるかを引き続きリサーチします。